# Were scientists in Ancient Egypt Egyptian, or were they from other regions?

Tags: ancient-egypt, science, north-africa

Do we have knowledge of any scientists of Ancient Egypt? If yes, were they originally from Egypt, or were they from other regions such as Europe, North Africa or Asia? Any examples?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_medicine) is your friend, and should be consulted, even better when preparing (open) questions than (standard) answers :)

Comment: I tried to edit in order to make it more readable, hopefully it will be accepted by mod and didn't remove any meaning intended by the OP

Comment: its question about Egypt scientists in person who made ancient Egypt

Comment: No one person made ancient Egypt.

Comment: @mdnth The point is that "ancient Egypt" covers thousands of years, and there would have been learned Greeks, Romans, and others at various times. Besides, the concept of "science" is a modern one should be applied carefully to other historical periods. So, at the very least, what do you mean by scientist, and what do you mean by Ancient Egypt?

Comment: i meant Ancient Egypt golden age,and what i meant with science    inventions and discoveries ,like building,astrology,their religion ..............

Comment: "or were they from other regions like Greek or Africa?" PS: Egypt is in Africa

Comment: "Scientists" before the 17th-19th century in Western Europe and its colonies, or the 19th-20th in the rest of the world is dubious.  "Science" as a practice coalesced very very late.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is yet another question based on completely counter-factual claims.

Comment: Turns out the original question did not make such a hard assumption of the existence of scientists, but that this assumption was introduced in later edits. I've rolled it back.

Comment: @mdnth You have accepted Anno2001's answer which seems to imply you are looking for more of a person who works in fields that we would today call "applied science" that weren't exactly grounded in science at the time. Or you're looking for something else that you haven't quite defined yet. Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: @SamuelRussell - sorry, I'll have to dispute you here. The formal notion of scientific method may be 1th century+, but people acting like scientists is as old as someone doing selective breeding (or figuring out the math for pyramid building to bring it on topic).

Comment: Try this on for size: "People putting penises in vaginas is as old as history.  Calling selective cultures built around instances of that act heterosexuality post dates the 19th century."  Also, I find it really hard to imagine isolated individuals prior to the 15th century engaged in peer review through journal article publication.  If we fail to appreciate that different acts bear different social meanings in different societies then we'll miss, for example, explanations of the religious content in Egyptian texts on disease treatment.

Comment: I want to know people who founded Egypt, the leading in astrology, , architecture..

Comment: There were no scientists in Egypt. Wtf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Imhotep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imhotep) was, as far as we know, native Egyptian.

Answer (score 9):

[Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science) is a modern concept, "a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions".

Although the ideas of science came gradually, and it is not possible to point out a single moment when science was born, the first real science and the first real scientists are usually attributed to the 15th to 17th century, and the [scientific revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_revolution).

In ancient Egypt there was for example no difference between medicine and magic. The famous architect, engineer and physician [Imenhotep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imhotep) (probably) wrote [a medical text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Smith_papyrus) that is well known for being very practical and having very little magic in it. But it too contains magical spells, showing that Imenhotep also did not adopt a wholly scientific attitude. Instead the text is probably low on magic because most of the ailments it is concerned with are external. Much of it deals with trauma, and it is probable that it was a text book rising out of, and used in, battle-field medicine.

So there were no scientists in ancient Egypt.

Comment: +1 : In ancient cultures, the terms mathematician, magician, astrologer, astronomer, scientist, etc were used interchangeably to a large extent, if they even had such vocabulary to distinguish between them.

Comment: ok, so how about those mathematicians, medicine experts, etc? Which region did they come from?

Comment: @LouisRhys: Do you have a reason to believe they came from any specific region? Most of them certainly were born in Egypt, some of them moved in. Same as in any empire, certainly.

Comment: @LennartRegebro no, I don't have any such reason, but it seems that it is the spirit of the question (the OP just used the word "scientists" wrongly). I remember seeing some debates in the social media about whether Egyptians or non-Egyptians are responsible for the Egyptian civilization, maybe the OP is referencing that.

Comment: @LouisRhys - "Which region did they come from" - the answer I posted might interest you.

Comment: of course a single person is too small a sample to answer so broad a question...

Comment: @jwenting: Yes and no. If there was one single scientist in ancient Egypt, then that would be an answer, of sorts. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro you can't know how many scientists there were from a single paper written by one of them. And that's the problem with things like this, we don't have population data that detailed from the period.

Comment: @jwenting Yeah, you are right.

Comment: @LouisRhys The question is still not specific about the age/period. Also, why would one assume that people coming from far lands where people had no agriculture or sizeable architecture would teach the Egyptians everything? And if they could, why would they do that? An interaction between cultures? Sure. "Stealing everything" from another civilization? That is a pretty dubious claim.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the flourishing of the New Kingdom:

> The New Kingdom of Egypt, also referred to as the Egyptian Empire, is
>   the period in ancient Egyptian history between the 16th century BC and
>   the 11th century BC, covering the Eighteenth, Nineteenth, and
>   Twentieth Dynasties of Egypt. The New Kingdom followed the Second
>   Intermediate Period and was succeeded by the Third Intermediate
>   Period. **It was Egypt’s most prosperous time and marked the peak of
>   its power.** [[Wikipedia - New Kingdom of Egypt]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Kingdom_of_Egypt)

The rise of the New Kingdom was immediately preceded by the rule of The Hyksos:

> The Hyksos... "foreign rulers" ... were a mixed people from West Asia
>   who took over the eastern Nile Delta , ending the thirteenth dynasty,
>   and initiating the Second Intermediate Period of Ancient Egypt.[[Wikipedia - Hyksos]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyksos)

i.e. The Hyksos were **not** Egyptians. See: [Modern scholarship usually assumes that the Hyksos were likely Semites who came from the Levant.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyksos#Origins_of_the_Hyksos)

Concerning the period of Hyksos rule, Egypt made many technological advances:

> The Hyksos brought several technical improvements to Egypt, as well as
>   cultural impulses such as new musical instruments and foreign loan
>   words. The changes introduced include new techniques of bronze working
>   and pottery, new breeds of animals, and new crops. In warfare, they
>   introduced the horse and chariot, the composite bow, improved battle
>   axes, and advanced fortification techniques. [Wikipedia - Hyksos]

Further, here is [a writer who directly connects the rise of the New Kingdom to Hysos innovations](http://www.bornemania.com/civ/readings/pp26_29.html):

> However, the presence of the Hyksos was not entirely negative for
>   Egypt. They introduced Egypt to Bronze Age technology by teaching the
>   Egyptians how to make bronze for use in new agricultural tools and
>   weapons. More significantly, **the Hyksos introduced new aspects of
>   warfare to Egypt, including the horse-drawn war chariot, a heavier
>   sword, and the compound bow. Eventually, a new line of pharaohs—the
>   eighteenth dynasty—made use of the new weapons to throw off Hyksos
>   domination, reunite Egypt, establish the New Kingdom (c. 1567-1085
>   b.c.e.), and launch the Egyptians along a new militaristic and
>   imperialistic path.** During the period of the New Kingdom, Egypt
>   became the most powerful state in the Middle East

Arguably, the zenith of Egyptian power and success, the New Kingdom period, was to a large extent the result of those innovations introduced by the Hyksos. If so, although we may not be able single out particular individuals who were or were not Egyptian, we can make a reasonable assertion that the flourishing of ancient Egyptian culture, exemplified by the New Kingdom period, was the result of the non-Egyptian science and technology introduced by the Hyksos.

*Disclaimer: I am by no means an Egyptologist, and I'm quite certain I've merely scratched the surface of a subject that has been discussed in far more depth in scholarly literature.*

(**An interesting aside concerning the Hyksos:** For those seeking extra-biblical support for the presence of the ancient Hebrews in Egypt, see: [The Hyksos continued to play a role in Egyptian literature:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyksos#Later_times)

> The Hyksos continued to play a role in Egyptian literature as a
>   synonym for "Asiatic" down to Hellenistic times...and this may have
>   led the Egyptian priest and historian Manetho to identify the coming
>   of the Hyksos with the sojourn in Egypt of Joseph and his brothers,
>   and led to some authors identifying the expulsion of the Hyksos with
>   the Exodus.

However, I believe that modern scholars have found little support for this claim.)

Comment: +1 but please, in future cut down on the blue and the italics.

Comment: It's better to format `"Ruritania was much better prepared to war against Neverland" ([source](...)).` or use `as [source](...) says, chief commander of Neverland was Ruritanian nationality`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no historical records, that I am aware of, which explicitly refer to any individual Scientists within PRE-Alexandrian, Ancient Egypt.

This does not automatically exclude the possibility of Archaeologists discovering evidence which specifically refers to individual ethnic Egyptian Scientists. However, at this point in time, there are no Ancient Egyptian Scientists to speak of.